# jQuery UI - datepicker - bug workaround for updating drop-down values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

It seems like there's a bug in datepicker when using the config settings

```
    changeYear  : true
    changeMonth : true
```

On https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year, if you select a date first, then exit the picker and re-enter and now change just the year (or month) via the drop-down the input field doesn't get updated. I believe the user expectation is that any changes done in the calendar "popup" are reflected in the input field once the pop-up is gone, ie we don't have to *explicitly* click the (same) day again if we just want to change day/month. 
Tried Chrome and MSIE and both exhibited the same behavior.

Does anybody have a workaround for this?

*EDIT:* This can **not** be fixed by adding the "done" button via

```
  showButtonPanel: true
```

as it has been suggested.

Thanks

Comment: No, not a bug.  It expects you to pick a month day and year.  If you want to change, you need to add a "done" button.   You can find examples and information searching StackOverflow.

Comment: If you think it's a bug I suggest reporting it to jquery ui team...

Comment: I added it to JQUI bug tracker yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

this has made its way into the jQuery UI bug tracker, but JakeCigar was nice enough to post a quick fix as follows:

```
     onChangeMonthYear:function(yy,mm,inst){
     var fmt     = $(this).datepicker('option', 'dateFormat')
     var newDate = new Date(inst.selectedYear,inst.selectedMonth,inst.selectedDay)
     $(this).val($.datepicker.formatDate(fmt,newDate))
     }
```